# super(type, object-or-type), MRO

Tags: python, super, method-resolution-order

```
    class B1(object):
        def f(self):
            print "B1.f"

    class B2(object):
        def f(self):
            print "B2.f"

    class D(B1, B2):
        pass

    d = D()
    super(B1, d).f()
    print B1.__mro__
```

Why does the above code print:

```
B2.f
(<class '__main__.B1'>, <type 'object'>)
```

whereas the documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super says:

```
super(type[, object-or-type]):
... The __mro__ attribute of the type lists the method resolution search order used by ... super().
```

It seems that the MRO, which is used, is not the one of the "type" parameter of super() but the one of the "object-or-type" parameter. Is this an error in the Python documentation?

Comment: I never noticed that error before. `super` always follows the second argument's MRO. That documentation should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation.